# mod_security nolog if body length more than

Tags: apache, mod-security2

Is there any way to set a secrule in modsecurity to filter (nolog) if the POST body length is smaller than 10 bytes?

I am logging all POST requests, just want to filter unwanted logs.

Comment: Can you try putting: 
SecRule REQUEST_BODY_LENGTH "@lt 10" "id:12345,phase:1,nolog,ctl:requestBodyAccess=off". Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257534/mod-security-a-rule-to-allow-post-requests-without-a-request-body , I modified the first answer and gave it to you as I do not have apache setup reasy with me. You might have to tune the value.

Comment: confirmed that the value after @lt 10 mens less than 10 bytes only.